# All browsers hang on windows 7 in tab says 'Waiting for...' need restart

Tags: windows-7, browser, freeze, internet-explorer-10, webpage

I'm having a frustrating problem with browsers on OS windows 7 home premium.

IE 10: My web browsing works ok for a while and then pages freeze and tab at top says "Waiting for ...' and never loads. Strangely I can still get to Google search results but if I click anything it freezes.

Chrome freezes too and says 'The page has become unresponsive ...kill page'

Safari stops also.

I have tried clearing cookies, cache, turning off Bitdefender firewall and nothing apart from a restart fixes it. consequently I am forced to restart my computer several times a day to stop this browser hang. I have no idea what could be causing this ..any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: are there any other network-related problems in that system besides web browsers?

Comment: So only browsers hang, not other programs?

Comment: I'm having similar problems on my Windows 10 box.  Firefox, Internet Explorer, and MS Edge all get similar symptoms, though the details are different.  I don't know how one is supposed to diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest configuring and using Opera and Firefox and reinstalling older and/or newer versions of the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same issue. The first time I rolled back to IE9 and it messed up the system. So I reinstalled the computer with IE9. This worked for a while until MS automatically installed IE10 during windows update. The first couple of days it seemed not too bad, but it became worse and worse. And the problem seems not limiting to IE. The chrome and firefox behaviored similarly. So I installed IE11 and hopefully it would work better. But still no improvement. Last night I rolled all way back to IE9 again. So far everything works. Even chrome and firefox work now. So I suspect by installing IE10, there is something changed in OS that caused all browsers not working correctly. Unfortunately, I could not find exactly what. My husband has window 8 with IE11. He used to have the same problem I had all the time. But he says he gets much less errors these days.